# What are the similarity of vuejs and nuxtjs when it comes to coding?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm new in coding and currently I'm studying Nuxtjs I've been watching several tutorial about Nuxtjs and its really hard to understand some function. I just want to ask if Vuesj and Nuxtjs had similarity when it comes to coding? If not, is it still work if I use VueJS coding structure in NuxtJs framework?

Comment: There is plenty of information about that on the Internet :)

Comment: Can you narrow your question? This is far too broad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nuxt is something on top of Vue, if you check [this page](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/ssr.html#Nuxt-js) you can see that it's mainly adding SSR (useful for SEO).
On top of this, it provides a flexible ecosystem with cool defaults and some conventions. You can live without it and organize your project with conventions, make your whole SSR-thing or just use Nuxt.

[The documentation](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/get-started/routing) should cover a lot of things like how to route, various hooks (`asyncData` and `fetch`), how to generate your project, how to automatically load some components, how to make SEO and a lot of other things.

Still, under the hood Nuxt is a Vue app on steroids and some stuff already done for you.

Answer (score 0):

Nuxt(framwwork for vue) is a framework for working with VueJS(framework for javascript) withing boundaries, and alongside good standards. There are also a lot of buit-in good practices, and it gives you structure for your files alongsite its many upsides.

TLDR: VueJS is a framework for javascript, NuxtJs is a framework built around the Vuejs framework. So you are using Vue, when you are using Nuxt.